# babel-plugin-transform-remove-console in production mode React Native

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I have installed

```
npm i babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save
```

Also added below code in `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```

But in production mode, its not removing `console.log`.

Also in some sample project `.babelrc` file is not getting generated after doing npm installation.Am I missing anything?

Reference [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-consolelog-statements)

Comment: Also having this issue.

Comment: post your project. I have the same setting and it works fine.

Comment: I currently have this problem. I'm using react-native 0.60.3 and "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4" ....

When I run ENVFILE=.env.production react-native run-android --variant=release I still see logs in the console.
@adamski did you find a solution ?

Comment: The answer to why it's not working for you guys is probably in this comment: "If you used create-react-app it might not be paying attention to your custom babel config, since it has all its own configs. You may need to eject the app in order to get this to work.". Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57224203/remove-console-log-statements-in-react-production-build